# Flutter - Conditional library import in flutter-web

Tags: flutter, dart, import, flutter-web

Supposing that `audioplayers|lib/audio_cache.dart` worked only on Android/iOS, I **conditionally exclude** the following import from a Dart file:

```
import "package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart"
```

in the following way:

```
import "dart:math" if (dart.library.io) "package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart";
```

where "dart:math" can be any fake_stub Dart file. In short this **imports a library only for mobile devices** in Flutter. Details [here](https://twitter.com/aloisdeniel/status/1148598679454048256) (thanks **Alois Deniel**!).

What would be the best way to hide platform-specific code in Flutter-Web implementation?

```
 import 'dart:io' show Platform;

 bool isMobile() => Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS;

 class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
     dynamic _audioPlayer;

     @override
     void initState() {
         if (isMobile()) {
            _audioPlayer = AudioCache(prefix: 'sounds/');
            _audioPlayer.load('mysound.mp3');
         }
     }
 }
```

This naive try fails on `AudioCache` reference of course.

```
 Error: Method not found: 'AudioCache'.
  _audioPlayer = AudioCache(prefix: 'sounds/');
```

Comment: I know this is not the core of the question, just an example, but I just updated the AudioCache class from the audioplayers package to fully support web :)

Answer (score 12):

In this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an) which has similar requirements as yours, I wrote an answer based on this implementation from [http](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/master/lib/src/client_stub.dart) package.

I think you can also use a similar approach to handle this conditional dependencies. I have provided a working example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713064/3043944). I am quoting the answer here.

> The core idea is as follows.
>
> 1. Create an abstract class to define the methods you will need to use in genral.
> 2. Create implementations specific to `web` and `android` dependencies which extends this abstract class.
> 3. Create a stub which exposes a method to return the instance of this abstract implementation. This is only to keep the dart analysis tool happy.
> 4. In the abstract class import this stub file along with the conditional imports specific for `mobile` and `web`. Then in its factory constructor return the instance of the specific implementation. This will be handled automatically by conditional import if written correctly.