# Flutter web with incompatible plugins

Tags: flutter

I'm planning to use one of my Flutter app as a web application. Unfortunately one of the plugin I'm using is not compatible for web. In my case I would be happy to exclude that feature which is using the incompatible plugin, but I'm not sure how to exclude (also plugin registration in pubspec.yaml) when targeting platform which is not supported by the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds similar to [Flutter - Conditional library import in flutter-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670361/flutter-conditional-library-import-in-flutter-web) - which I found with a simple google search.